# jQuery Ajax if variable on submit is ok hide button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to hide the submit button if the email is the same with the one in the database from action.php. How could I implement this in my following code:

```
<form onsubmit="return submitdata();">
    <input type="text" id="mail">
    <input type="submit" value="Check">
</form>

<p id="msg"></p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function submitdata()
{
    var name=document.getElementById('mail').value;

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'action.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {
        'name':name
    },
    cache:false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#msg').html(data);
    }
});

return false;
}

</script>
```

action.php:

```
<?php 
require_once 'config.php';
$email_ck=$_POST['name'];
if(extract($crud->get_email($email_ck))){
    echo "Response: ".$email;
    $hide = 1;
}else{
    echo 'hmmmm';
}
?>
```

When the email coincide I get the correct message, but how could I call back $hide to determine to hide my submit button?

Comment: Your response should indicate to your jQuery success callback rather to hide the form or not.

Comment: What is being logged in the success callback?

Comment: And how can I do that. My Ajax knowledge is limited :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning a message, return an indication.
(In the JS script write the message accordingly)

A detailed json string would be a good idea but for simplification see the following.

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
require_once 'config.php';
$email_ck=$_POST['name'];
if(extract($crud->get_email($email_ck))){
    echo "already_exists";
}else{
    echo 'not_exists';
}
?>
```

**JS:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'action.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {
        'name':name
    },
    cache:false,
    success: function (data) {
        if(data == 'already_exists'){
           $('#buttonId').hide();
        } else if(data == 'not_exists'){
           $('#msg').html('Response: ' +name);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Pefect. That worked like a charm. Thanks stranger ^_^